# Android MenuDrawer api by simon VT

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have encountered a problem in the [MenuDrawer library by SimonVT](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer).

In this the main part does not refresh on click or anyother changes. The screen refreshes only when the menudrawer is drawn once again that too only with the last touched change
I have an expandable list view in the main view and this menu drawer. The list view does not expand when touched, but expands once i swipe for the menudrawer
Is there a way to refresh the screen without swiping the menudrawer

Answer (score 0):

The library has been **deprecated** by the author. This means that it is no longer being updated in in effect no longer supported. I recommend using the

Navigation drawer which has been implemented in the android api.

Relevant api documentation:
[Creating a navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)